# Getting Exception in mappers test 'ParameterResolutionException'

Tags: java, junit, mockito, mapper

I have two domain classes User and UserDTO

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class User {
    private String name;
    private String email;
}

@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class UserDTO {
    private String name;
    private String email;
}
```

and I have configured a Mapper class

```
import org.mapstruct.Builder;
import org.mapstruct.Mapper;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;

@Mapper
        (
                componentModel = "spring",
                builder = @Builder(disableBuilder = true),
                imports = {LocalDateTime.class}
        )
public abstract class UserToUserDTOMapper {
    public abstract UserDTO mapUserToUserDTO(User user);

    public abstract User mapUserDTOToUser(UserDTO userDTO);
}
```

I can see the Mapper class generated in the generated source

I have written a Unit Test For it

```
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;

@RequiredArgsConstructor
class UserToUserDTOMapperTest {
    private final UserToUserDTOMapper mapper;

    String NAME = "asd";
    String EMAIL = "asd@gmail.com";

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
    }

    @Test
    public void testMapUserToUserDTO() {
        User user = User.builder().name(NAME).email(EMAIL).build();
        UserDTO userDTO = mapper.mapUserToUserDTO(user);
        assertNotNull(userDTO);
        assertEquals(NAME, userDTO.getName());
        assertEquals(EMAIL, userDTO.getEmail());
    }
}
```

But When I try to execute the test , It Fails with the error message
**org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ParameterResolutionException: No ParameterResolver registered for parameter [final com.asd.mapper.UserToUserDTOMapper mapper] in constructor [public com.asd.mapper.UserToUserDTOMapperTest(com.asd.mapper.UserToUserDTOMapper)]**

Comment: Manually instantiate mapper like
private UserToUserDTOMapper mapper = new UserToUserDTOMapperImpl();
And remove '@beforeEach' method and @RequiredArgConstructor. you do not need it

Comment: @Feelfree : I dont think thats a good idea , DI is already injecting the mapper instance.

Comment: can you post your entire stack track?

Answer (score 0):

Since `mapper` is `final`, `@RequiredArgsConstructor` is creating a constructor like:

```java
UserToUserDTOMapperTest(UserToUserDTOMapper mapper) {
    this.mapper = mapper;
}
```

Now, when JUnit tries to instantiate the test class, it cannot resolve that constructor parameter – hence the `ParameterResolutionException`.

You are using MapStruct, so you can change the test as follows:

```java
// No @RequiredArgsConstructor / Lombok needed.
class UserToUserDTOMapperTest {

    UserToUserDTOMapper classUnderTest = Mappers.getMapper(UserToUserDTOMapper.class);

    String NAME = "asd";
    String EMAIL = "asd@gmail.com";

    @Test
    void testMapUserToUserDTO() {
        User user = User.builder()
                .name(NAME)
                .email(EMAIL)
                .build();

        UserDTO userDTO = classUnderTest.mapUserToUserDTO(user);

        assertNotNull(userDTO);
        assertEquals(NAME, userDTO.getName());
        assertEquals(EMAIL, userDTO.getEmail());
    }
}
```

See also:

https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#mappers-factory